# Can't open silverlight application in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, silverlight

This is regarding 
Visual Studio pro 2008 sp1, with resharper and testdriven installed.

I've just installed:
Microsoft Silverlight Projects 2008
Version 9.0.30729.146

I find I can't open a silverlight application due to a 'missing patch'. The error dialog directs me back to the download page for the silverlight tools I just installed. (And uninstalled and reinstalled.) I've never installed any beta versions of anything. The google hits for this error go to blog pages that refer to beta version problems, and to the same download I've already installed.

This does not bode well for doing anything with silverlight at this point, the tools won't even run. I really don't want another research project at this point just to get it running. Hope someone knows an easy fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The useless error message should say "visual web developer" not installed. They don't check this crucial prerequisite during the tools install. And you can't install visual web developer after you have installed visual studio sp1. vs2008 has to be uninstalled, reinstalled, and sp1 applied. Then the silverlight tools have to be uninstalled, reinstalled. What a joke.

Comment: If by "visual web developer" you mean the express product; I've **never** installed this, and work on silverlight projects regularly.

Comment: Or do you mean that you unchecked the web tools when installing VS2008? Yes, it'll need those...

Comment: I'm sorry that has been frustrating for you, but at least you shouldn't have to do it again...

Answer (score 0):

I just spent most of yesterday and today with this issue. Using VS 2010 and Silverlight 4. Projects open fine in Blend but I get the error "The project type is not supported by this installation." in VS.

The three things that seem to have mattered are installing these items:

- the VS Web Development tools. Do this from the Programs and Features control panel. 
  --- Pick your VS product, then Uninstall/Change. The setup will open in maintenance mode. 
  --- After it loads, click next.
  --- Select the add/remove features choice and select **Visual Web Developer**. This seems to be key. I only have it and C# installed and it works.
- The Silverlight Plugin for Developers. VS will prompt you with an error dialog and a link. Click it and install. I am using lameo IE so can't find the URL now that I've restarted.
- The Silverlight 4 Tools for VS.
  --- http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=18149
  --- Use this link. I used other links and apparently they aren't quite the right stuff.

I also installed the VS 2010 SP 1 package, but honestly don't know if that makes a difference. It took these three for SL projects to show without an error. Hope this helps somebody!!